# correlation measures between multi categorical variables and continuous variables

Tags: data-science, correlation

I have dataset that target[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMYw4.jpg) has 6 type (0,1,2,3,4,5,6) . Do I need to dummy target column in to six column to find correlation between target and input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try one hot encoding, as in [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/) and create a dummy variable for each category of your 7.